# Dockerfile for mulitple stage and npm private registry

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

i've a question for my Dockerfile.

This is my dockerfile:

```
# Builder stage
FROM node:18-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN rm -f .npmrc
COPY package*.json ./
COPY snkrs-url.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./
COPY . .
RUN npm config set @myorg:registry http://packages:8390/npm/p/myorg/npm/
RUN npm config set //packages:8390/npm/p/myorg/npm/:_authToken=etoken
RUN npm install && npm run build
RUN npm prune --production
RUN wget https://gobinaries.com/tj/node-prune --output-document - | /bin/sh && node-prune

# Runner stage
FROM node:18-alpine as runner
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/snkrs-url.json ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
```

But return an error for connection refused:

FetchError: request to http://localhost:8390/npm/p/myorg/npm/@myorg/node-discord-webhook/-/node-discord-webhook-1.0.0.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8390

The registry is in my personal docker container for jetbrains space. and if i try to launch npm install it works.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

```
# Builder stage
FROM node:18 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY snkrs-url.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./
COPY . .
RUN npm config delete proxy
RUN npm config set @sneakers-monitor:registry http://packages:8390/npm/p/sneakers-monitor/npm/
RUN npm config set //packages:8390/npm/p/sneakers-monitor/npm/:_authToken=eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxbjdENmoxc1Y0ZHQiLCJhdWQiOiJjaXJjbGV0LXdlYi11aSIsIm9yZ0RvbWFpbiI6ImpldGJyYWlucyIsIm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDg0IiwicGVybV90b2tlbiI6IjJuWHFuRDRYRTVCTiIsInByaW5jaXBhbF90eXBlIjoiVVNFUiIsImlhdCI6MTY3MDY3Njk1Mn0.g7sOBo7r7SvNuWq7VvKttdusdMf5Vad2Als24xBuGFDBId1oGa6XG61Y6X98mE_lifvtMxydD5DFspe49lH2TyS2hhNUI2vYxMno9jcA3oWGNjXMuK8cpAEterD70aNl_yCT-bS2hTh0jeVUKtLewGvoiXIPOvrCTMnyYpHA_qmixi1Qtw49O5rnB9SzTx6Go_iHUJB1p4ZFhEvY_mH8AVFSTo00YRE-RQEQ0j3p54me9amlC5xUTRg6c3bI5J9ElqVPgKn2arODsITKtYkD3vS6K3MRUtCnrr2eKxw3LtDYH1GfXq-hCw5TlYxWiBB_z21U7tnpOCKM8GkxrH-E3hdlYwt4ychoFveDclQKCC8PsMVOWOI9oaMqVttWMz9HkgvAEB3y--pV54s_pHm6xrH_CrYL2oEZ6rELjyJDaZYB-EPpLOrRRIXOYlitYUpe8nKcz13I7HEChpT0huXiP6IWqdotvtSdnR89irqoDILH7RZbGGjkFYB6Yz04zPwzn91-CBONuTMRLm39iv880l2tU6-7BlM2Jivyx0I_IKJCqJjymE0zfXJqB9I1F1S4T2GHBALHbTXtXa9dgC-unwJN3L_4TEPxaozzzcH8ikld8GOcd3bXJX1d-iD4GjqX9ek8cidwqmRzR3ZobAVKnb7_NC0vrXxG14BTqrvJNBg
RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build
RUN npm prune --production
RUN wget https://gobinaries.com/tj/node-prune --output-document - | /bin/sh && node-prune

# Runner stage
FROM node:18-alpine as runner
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/snkrs-url.json ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
```

now with this dockerfile i've this error:

```
17 184.6 npm ERR! network request to http://packages:8390/npm/p/sneakers-monitor/npm/@sneakers-monitor%2fdiscord-bot failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND packages
#17 184.6 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
#17 184.6 npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
#17 184.6 npm ERR! network
#17 184.6 npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
#17 184.6 npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
#17 184.6
#17 184.6 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#17 184.6 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-19T18_20_53_636Z-debug-0.log
```

EDIT2:

```
this is my docker-compose:

version: '3.8'

services:
    init-configs:
        image: "public.registry.jetbrains.space/p/space-on-premises/docker/init-configs:2022.1.0-BETA"
        volumes:
        - config:/home/init-config/config
        environment:
            AUTOMATION_TAG: "2022.1.0-BETA.1596"
    space:
        image: "public.registry.jetbrains.space/p/space-on-premises/docker/space:2022.1.0-BETA"
        volumes:
        - config:/home/space/circlet-server-onprem/config
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: "-Dconfig.file=/home/space/circlet-server-onprem/config/space.on-premises.conf"
        depends_on:
            init-configs:
                condition: service_completed_successfully
            vcs:
                condition: service_started
            redis:
                condition: service_started
            postgres:
                condition: service_started
            elasticsearch:
                condition: service_healthy
            minio:
                condition: service_started
        ports:
        - "8084:8084"
        networks:
        - "frontend"
        - "backend-apps"
        - "backend-data"

    vcs:
        image: "public.registry.jetbrains.space/p/space-on-premises/docker/vcs-hosting:2022.1.0-BETA"
        volumes:
        - config:/home/space/git/vcs-hosting/config
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: '-Dproperties.file=config/vcs.on-premises.properties'
        depends_on:
            init-configs:
                condition: service_completed_successfully
            redis:
                condition: service_started
            postgres:
                condition: service_started
            elasticsearch:
                condition: service_healthy
            minio:
                condition: service_started
        ports:
        - "2222:2222"
        - "8080:8080"
        networks:
        - "frontend"
        - "backend-apps"
        - "backend-data"

    packages:
        image: "public.registry.jetbrains.space/p/space-on-premises/docker/packages:2022.1.0-BETA"
        volumes:
        - config:/home/space/packages-server/config
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: '-Dconfig.file=/home/space/packages-server/config/packages.on-premises.conf'
        depends_on:
            init-configs:
                condition: service_completed_successfully
            redis:
                condition: service_started
            postgres:
                condition: service_started
            elasticsearch:
                condition: service_healthy
            minio:
                condition: service_started
        ports:
        - "8390:8390"
        - "9390:9390"
        networks:
        - "frontend"
        - "backend-apps"
        - "backend-data"

    langservice:
        image: "public.registry.jetbrains.space/p/space-on-premises/docker/langservice:2022.1.0-BETA"
        volumes:
        - config:/home/space/langservice-server/config
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: "-Dconfig.file=/home/space/langservice-server/config/langservice.on-premises.conf"
        depends_on:
            init-configs:
                condition: service_completed_successfully
        ports:
        - "8095"
        networks:
        - "backend-apps"

    postgres:
        image: "postgres:12.2"
        volumes:
         - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: space
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: spacepassword
            POSTGRES_DB: spacedb
        ports:
        - "5432"
        networks:
        - "backend-data"

    elasticsearch:
        image: "elasticsearch:7.17.4"
        volumes:
        - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        environment:
            ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
            discovery.type: single-node
            xpack.security.enabled: "false"
        ports:
        - "9200"
        - "9300"
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9200/_cat/health" ]
            interval: 5s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 10
            start_period: 20s
        networks:
        - "backend-data"

    redis:
        image: "redis:7.0.2-alpine"
        ports:
        - "6379"
        networks:
        - "backend-data"

    minio:
        image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2022-03-05T06-32-39Z
        volumes:
        - minio_data:/data
        environment:
            MINIO_ROOT_USER: space-access-key
            MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: space-secret-key
        command: server --address :9000 --console-address :9001 --compat /data
        ports:
        - "9000:9000"
        - "9001"
        networks:
        - "backend-data"

    jenkins:
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits: 
                    memory: 1G
        ports:
            - 10007:8080
            - 10008:50000
        volumes:
            - jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
        networks:
            - "backend-data"
volumes:
    elasticsearch_data: {}
    db_data: {}
    minio_data: {}
    config: {}
    jenkins: {}

networks:
    frontend: {}
    backend-apps: {}
    backend-data: {}
```

docker compose is the docker-compose for jetbrains space

Comment: I guess while building the image it cant solve the url for your npm registry. Expose your npm registry container to 8390 or map it in a docker-compose. Then try from docker image to access docker.host.internal:8390 instead of packages:8390.  If this works please let me know. Not a solution for production.

Comment: @Ralle the npm registry is exposed on container to 8390, in the docker compose the image of 'packages' is in a network with other container

Comment: I just tested a bit. In my host file it is host.docker.internal not docker.host.internal. I executed: RUN  nc -zv host.docker.internal 8080  On 8080 i have runing another container. Worked. so i guess it will resolve also your npm registry.

Comment: i try with host..docker.internal but not work, edit my post with new dockerfile

Comment: If you post your docker-compose with the npm registry i will try to find out the error.

Comment: @Ralle i add the docker compose and edit the dockerfile