# Docker and NPM private registry

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

i use jetbrains space-on-permises on my pc. When i try to build a node docker image with a npm registry set in the npm registry i've a error:

this is my docker file:

```
# Builder stage
FROM node:18 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY snkrs-url.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./
COPY . .
RUN npm config delete proxy
RUN npm config set @sneakers-monitor:registry http://packages:8390/npm/p/sneakers-monitor/npm/
RUN npm config set //packages:8390/npm/p/sneakers-monitor/npm/:_authToken=eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxbjdENmoxc1Y0ZHQiLCJhdWQiOiJjaXJjbGV0LXdlYi11aSIsIm9yZ0RvbWFpbiI6ImpldGJyYWlucyIsIm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDg0IiwicGVybV90b2tlbiI6IjJuWHFuRDRYRTVCTiIsInByaW5jaXBhbF90eXBlIjoiVVNFUiIsImlhdCI6MTY3MDY3Njk1Mn0.g7sOBo7r7SvNuWq7VvKttdusdMf5Vad2Als24xBuGFDBId1oGa6XG61Y6X98mE_lifvtMxydD5DFspe49lH2TyS2hhNUI2vYxMno9jcA3oWGNjXMuK8cpAEterD70aNl_yCT-bS2hTh0jeVUKtLewGvoiXIPOvrCTMnyYpHA_qmixi1Qtw49O5rnB9SzTx6Go_iHUJB1p4ZFhEvY_mH8AVFSTo00YRE-RQEQ0j3p54me9amlC5xUTRg6c3bI5J9ElqVPgKn2arODsITKtYkD3vS6K3MRUtCnrr2eKxw3LtDYH1GfXq-hCw5TlYxWiBB_z21U7tnpOCKM8GkxrH-E3hdlYwt4ychoFveDclQKCC8PsMVOWOI9oaMqVttWMz9HkgvAEB3y--pV54s_pHm6xrH_CrYL2oEZ6rELjyJDaZYB-EPpLOrRRIXOYlitYUpe8nKcz13I7HEChpT0huXiP6IWqdotvtSdnR89irqoDILH7RZbGGjkFYB6Yz04zPwzn91-CBONuTMRLm39iv880l2tU6-7BlM2Jivyx0I_IKJCqJjymE0zfXJqB9I1F1S4T2GHBALHbTXtXa9dgC-unwJN3L_4TEPxaozzzcH8ikld8GOcd3bXJX1d-iD4GjqX9ek8cidwqmRzR3ZobAVKnb7_NC0vrXxG14BTqrvJNBg
RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build
RUN npm prune --production
RUN wget https://gobinaries.com/tj/node-prune --output-document - | /bin/sh && node-prune

# Runner stage
FROM node:18-alpine as runner
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/snkrs-url.json ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
```

And this is the error:

```
#18 188.0 npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
#18 188.0 npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
#18 188.0 npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
#18 188.0 npm ERR! network request to http://packages:8390/npm/p/sneakers-monitor/npm/@sneakers-monitor%2fdiscord-bot failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND packages
#18 188.0 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
#18 188.0 npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
#18 188.0 npm ERR! network
#18 188.0 npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
#18 188.0 npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
#18 188.0
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's wrong with your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74852067/dockerfile-for-mulitple-stage-and-npm-private-registry

Comment: My other question have more edit. Sorry for duplicate but this is more clean and short